# MySQL Query not selecting correct date range

Tags: mysql, date

Im currently trying to run a SQL query to export data between a certain date, but it runs the query fine, just not the date selection and i can't figure out what's wrong.

```
SELECT 
    title AS Order_No, 
    FROM_UNIXTIME(entry_date, '%d-%m-%Y') AS Date, 
    status AS Status,
    field_id_59 AS Transaction_ID,  
    field_id_32 AS Customer_Name, 
    field_id_26 AS Sub_Total, 
    field_id_28 AS VAT, 
    field_id_31 AS Discount, 
    field_id_27 AS Shipping_Cost, 
    (field_id_26+field_id_28+field_id_27-field_id_31) AS Total 
FROM 
    exp_channel_data AS d NATURAL JOIN
    exp_channel_titles AS t
WHERE 
    t.channel_id = 5 AND FROM_UNIXTIME(entry_date, '%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN '01-05-2012' AND '31-05-2012' AND status = 'Shipped'  
ORDER BY 
    entry_date DESC
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-literals.html), date literals should be in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.  Also, bearing in mind the point made by @ypercube in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10652693/623041), you want:

```
WHERE t.channel_id = 5
  AND entry_date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-05-01')
  AND entry_date <  UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-06-01')
  AND status = 'Shipped'
```

Comment: An easy way to remember this perhaps is that it's most to least significant.

Comment: Thank you - that worked! I was trying to change the way the date looked when it was exported so i thought i had to then keep it in that order. It works now though. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the date format there is another issue. To effectively use any index on `entry_date`, you should not apply functions to that column when you use it conditions in `WHERE`, `GROUP BY` or `HAVING` clauses (you can use the formatting in `SELECT` list, if you need a different than the default format to be shown). An effective way to write that part of the query would be:

```
 (  entry_date >= '2012-05-01'  
AND entry_date < '2012-06-01' 
 )
```

It works with `DATE`, `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` columns.

Comment: Great point! +1  I've updated my answer to reflect this (and to bear in mind that `entry_date` may merely be an integer holding the unix timestamp).